# Read Image Dataset into Python's application

Tags: python, image, image-processing, file-upload, conv-neural-network

I have a image set (+-18k images, different sizes, all colored) that I'd like to read as an array into python. The goal is to explore the images - through color histograms, ie - and also processing them to a CNN image classification.

I'm able to do so by keras datagenerator (flow_from_directory), but in such mode I guess I can't do the exploration part (at least I don't know how).

Also, I scraped those images, so they are not beautifully placed in folders and subfolders (classes and sets) as datagenerator demands (and all tutorials are based on), the labels are in a .csv file and I need to keep moving them by some ugly script as I change labels for different experiments.

All this happens because I do not have enough compute power, so I'm using Google Colab with memory of 12GB, so is not enough to read all images in memory without crashing (about 20% of the dataset). The moving-thing workaroung is also frustrating because of Google colab and drive, since it relies upon Internet to do so.

At this point, after A LOT of tutorials and many stackoverflow questions, ANY hint or advice will be very welcome. Am I doing the 'smart' way?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best bet would be to use a tool designed for dataset exploration rather than writing a script to do this yourself. Something like the open-source tool, [FiftyOne](https://fiftyone.ai), is made exactly for the purpose of [visualizing large image datasets](https://voxel51.com/docs/fiftyone/user_guide/dataset_creation/index.html), exploring various views into your data, adding multiple label fields for different experiments, and iterating through it to [pass your data on to train deep networks](https://medium.com/p/17cac2c22fa8).

[image]

It backs your labels in a database and only loads images as needed so memory shouldn't be an issue. You can also [use it within Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/voxel51/fiftyone-examples/blob/master/examples/quickstart.ipynb).

Comment: .
I'll test it. Until your answer, I've been working with work around scripts and batches. Thank you! I can't upvoted your response, though, not enough reputation.